# Understanding unless

Tags: logic

Write this proposition in the form of "if p, then q"

> Mary will go swimming unless the water is too cold.

I will answer:

> if the water is not too cold, then Mary will go swimming.

Is this correct btw?

Comment: I'd interpret it to mean "Mary will go swimming *if and only if* the water is not too cold", so I'm not sure the question itself can be answered since this cannot be put in the form "if $p$, then $q$".

Comment: "Understanding unless" ? Look here : https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14603/why-is-unless-considered-a-conditional-disjunction-rather-than-an-equivalence . No, it really is philosophical.

Comment: Well honestly i kinda confuses when my lecturer said the answer is: If the water is too cold, then Mary will go swimming

Comment: You are right to be confused. Your proposed answer is the correct one : " If the water is **not** too cold, then Mary will go swimming".

Comment: '$P$ unless $Q$' is a bit tricky ... by it, we definitely mean that '$P$ is the case as long as $Q$ is not the case' ... which translates to $\neg Q \rightarrow P$ ... but sometimes we *add* to that 'but once $Q$ does become the case, then $P$ ceases to be the case .. which itself translates into $Q \rightarrow \neg P$, and so combined with the first part, you would get $\neg Q \leftrightarrow P$. So, when faced with an 'unless', the question is: can we assume that the stronger $\neg Q \leftrightarrow P$ is meant, or should we just stick to the weaker $\neg Q \rightarrow P$?

Comment: Your answer does not rule out the possibility that Mary will go swimming even if the water is too cold. To do so, your answer should be a biconditional.  Then, if the water is too cold, Mary will NOT go swimming.